# Get specific href value with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the bellow html code. I would like to get the href value of the second li "https://regex101.com/#javascript". I try with expression: `<a class="tt-website" href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>` and then I've used JavaScript exec() Method. From the returned array I get `https://regex101.com/#javascript" target="new`

```
<div class="row social-media-row">
<ul class="tt-wrapper">
    <li><a class="tt-map popup-gmaps" href="https://www.google.com/maps"><span>Map</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="tt-website" href="https://regex101.com/#javascript" target="new"><span>Website</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="tt-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="new"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="tt-video popup-gmaps" href=""><span>Video</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason not to get the element by it's class name and access it through the conventional API? You may not need regex at all.

Comment: Yoda I can't do that because the code is actually a text from an textarea input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the greedy `.*`, use this:

```
<a class="tt-website" href="([^"]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /href="(.*)"\s+/g; 
var str = '<a class="tt-website" href="https://regex101.com/#javascript" target="new"><span>Website</span></a>';
var m;
 
m = str.match(re);

document.write(m);
```

https://regex101.com/r/yY3gR0/1